# How to show the validation messages together

Tags: javascript

I need your assistant and help in modifying the below code to show the validation messages if not satisfied together not one by one. My code is:

```
function validateForm()
 {
            var x = "";
            var y = "";


      if ( (RFC.C1.checked) && (!RFC.Language_e.checked || !RFC.Language_e.checked  ))
        {
        y += "Please Select the Language";
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = y;
        return false;
        }         
      else if (document.RFC.Reason.value=="")
        {
        x += "Please enter a Reason";
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = x;
        return false;
        }    
        else
        {
        return true;
        }
```

}

In addition, the validation message is shown one time and if the user didn't correct it and submit the page, the error will not be shown again. Can you please help in the two issues?

Comment: You should store them in a container (push them into an array) and show it together.

Comment: read JS book, first one that you meet, don't waist time of other people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var error = "";
    var valid = true;


    if ( (RFC.C1.checked) && (!RFC.Language_e.checked || !RFC.Language_e.checked  )) {
        error += "<li><a href=\"#lang\">Please Select the Language</a></li>";
        valid = false;
    }         
    else if (document.RFC.Reason.value=="") {
        error += "<li><a href=\"reason\">Please enter a Reason</a></li>";
        valid = false;
    }    

    if(valid === false) {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<ul>" + error + "</ul>";
    }
    return valid;
}
```

- Get all your errors and store them.
- Change the valid boolean to false if any single or multiple error occurs
- Only display errors if they happen.
- Link to the error locations in your page for easy navigation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use your code and it helped me alot however, I am still not able to show the all in once and once two validation errors is there, the code will not show the error

Comment: More code is probably needed. Put a sample on JSFiddle to show the problem.

Comment: It is a pure HTML and now I am building the javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validateForm()
    {
          var x = "";
          var y = "";
          var z = "";

          if ( (RFC.C1.checked) && (!RFC.Language_e.checked || !RFC.Language_e.checked) )
          {
            y += "Please Select the Language";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = y;
            return false;
          }         
          else if ( document.RFC.Reason.value=="" )
          {
            x += "Please enter a Reason";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = x;
            return false;
          } 
          else if ( ((RFC.C1.checked) && (!RFC.Language_e.checked || !RFC.Language_e.checked  )) && (document.RFC.Reason.value=="") )
          {   
            z += "Please enter a Reason and Language";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = z;
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            return true;
          }        
    }
```

By the way your code is working but not nice. You should read something about programming style. To get nice validation quicly you can use jQuery Validate plug-in.